# What Kivy Tutorials Are Available

Tags: python, kivy

What Kivy tutorials and learning aids exist?   Where is the list for Kivy?

This is besides the pong tutorial on their website?

Comment: Did you take a look at the examples distributed with Kivy's installation?

Comment: at the kivy installation dir ... `Kivy-1.2.0-w32/kivy/examples`

Comment: @GannonLawlor: MrJames is right, examples distributed with Kivy installation are placed in Kivy installation directory.

Comment: Can't answer because it's closed.   There is now an examples/ directory in the installation and a "Kivy Crash Course" series of videos.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As others suggested, the [examples](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples) in the kivy_installation directory are there to help programmers understand how basic tasks can be done using kivy.

There is also this [snippet wiki](http://wiki.kivy.org/) where we encourage people to put there snippets in the [user snippets](http://wiki.kivy.org/User%20Snippets) section.

You could also look at the [your first widget](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html) section in the [programming guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide-index.html)

I guess we need to be better at explaining that. There is an effort at a new [getting started](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#doc-introduction) that aims at helping to introduce the different parts of the documentation that are otherwise not quite obvious to new comers, suggestions are welcome. You can open a issue on [github](http://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) for documentation, we will be also adding a suggestion section to the documentation.

Comment: When the basic tutorials have you up to speed or if you learn better by example, here are some: https://github.com/encukou/touchgames/graphs/contributors, https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/List-of-Kivy-Projects